# Open source software to view menstrual phase on multiple devices

Tags: offline, mobile, desktop-client, health

I want to see which phase of my menstrual cycle I'm currently in, no matter which device I'm on (laptop or phone). A simple status/notification of "luteal" etc will do. Any reliable calculation will do.

Ideal features:

- based on local calculations, no synching
- adjust the projection to match actual cycle

Optional / unimportant features:

- recording symptoms
- fertility tracking

Comment: the tricky part is finding programs on different platforms that use the same methodology

Comment: https://arnowelzel.de/wp/projekte/periodical

Comment: https://linuxorg.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Which operating systems do you use on the laptop/phone?